# Why does hg gexport not work with the --cwd parameter?

Tags: mercurial, hg-git

Question title is pretty much the question.  Here's a look at what I get:

[image]

I am trying to export a mercurial repository to git, but to a different directory.  hg gexport works just fine without the `--cwd` parameter, but I don't want that -- I want to change the working directory to another one, but strangely, it says `unknown command` when I use that command line switch.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Real `hgexport` is not native `hg` command, it's part of [hggit extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HgGit)
2. According to wiki, this part ("Using hg-git to interact with a hg repository with git") is outdated and may not reflect current state of extension
3. `>hg gexport --cwd $PATH` work in my own tests without errors (so-so, see below) with command-line *expanded accordingly to requirements*

   > hg gexport --cwd i:\Work\Personal!whyhq\ -R i:\Work\Personal!whyhq\site

without -R gexport will **not** find source hg-repo after `cd`to target location

4. And last, but not least: even properly used, `hgexport` in current hggit

   `hg id`

   `15457fc67631 0.8.13`

do **nothing** (nothing changed on target). I suppose, for getting git-repo from hg you have to use trivial `hg push <git-URL>` today (yes, it work, with *minimal tricks* on your side: `branch_bookmark_suffix = $STRING` in .hgrc)

## Side note

If you have hggit extension enabled (globally or per-repository) hg-repo is mirrored automagically into bare git-repo (at least it seems so) in `.hg/git` directory, you can just copy&rename it

Comment: Yep -- you have to use the -R switch.  I guess I assumed it would default to the current directory.